# How do I setup the date as 'MM/DD/YYYY' format and "Percentage" results for the following query

Tags: sql, date, format, date-format

Here is my query and I am having a brain freeze on how to convert the results to reflect date as "MM/DD/YYYY" format and so that the results print out as a percentage instead of a decimal output.

```
c.execute("""WITH num_requests AS (
             SELECT time::date AS day, count(*)
             FROM log
             GROUP BY time::date
             ORDER BY time::date
            ), num_errors AS (
             SELECT time::date AS day, count(*)
             FROM log
             WHERE status != '200 OK'
             GROUP BY time::date
             ORDER BY time::date
            ), error_rate AS (
             SELECT num_requests.day,
                num_errors.count::float / num_requests.count::float * 100
                AS error_pc
             FROM num_requests, num_errors
             WHERE num_requests.day = num_errors.day
            )
            SELECT * FROM error_rate WHERE error_pc > 1
        """)
```

Comment: Are you using Postgres?  Please show us your current output and why it is not what you want.  To fix the percentage issue, you may round, then cast to text and append a `%` sign at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A [PostgreSQL date](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date/) formats by default as YYYY-MM-DD. If a date is stored as a string in that same format, you can [typecast](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/) it to a date, just as you did using`::date`.  Having it as a date, you can format it again as text string using the [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html) function.

```
to_char(time::date,'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

The same [to_char](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html) function will help you represent a number as a percent. However if the number is a rate and not a percent, then you will need to do the multiplying:

```
to_char(100*rate,'FM999.90"%"') AS pct
```

However, I would recommend to control and execute formatting from within your host language (Java, Python, etc). I think it is a cleaner approach to leave formatting out of your SQL.